# Web Socket in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, javascript, sockets, websocket, tomcat7

I am new in web socket. I had learned some tutorial to implement web socket. But it is not working properly. I don't know what I have done wrongly.

**note:** I have not done any configuration (web.xml) and I have been used tomcat 7.0.47,jdk 1.6.0_24

**This is My Server side code:**

```
package com.hmkcode;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.websocket.EncodeException;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value="/websocket/{client-id}")
public class MyServerEndpoint {

    private static final LinkedList<Session> clients = new LinkedList<Session>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        clients.add(session);
    }
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message,@PathParam("client-id") String clientId) {
        for (Session client : clients) {
            try {
                client.getBasicRemote().sendObject(clientId+": "+message);            

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (EncodeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session peer) {
        clients.remove(peer);
    }
}
```

**This is my Web client code**

```
var URL = "ws://localhost:8080/WebSocket1/websocket/web-client";
var websocket;

$(document).ready(function(){
    connect(); 
});

function connect(){
        websocket = new WebSocket(URL);
        websocket.onopen = function(evnt) { onOpen(evnt);};
        websocket.onmessage = function(evnt) { onMessage(evnt); };
        websocket.onerror = function(evnt) { onError(evnt); };
}
function sendMessage() {
    websocket.send($("#message").val());
}
function onOpen() {
    updateStatus("connected");
}
function onMessage(evnt) {
    if (typeof evnt.data == "string") {

        $("#received_messages").append(
                        $('<tr/>')
                        .append($('<td/>').text("1"))
                        .append($('<td/>').text(evnt.data.substring(0,evnt.data.indexOf(":"))))
                        .append($('<td/>').text(evnt.data.substring(evnt.data.indexOf(":")+1))));
    }
}
function onError(evnt) {
    alert('ERROR: ' + evnt.data);
}
function updateStatus(status){
    if(status == "connected"){
        $("#status").removeClass (function (index, css) {
           return (css.match (/\blabel-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
        });
        $("#status").text(status).addClass("label-success");
    }
}
```

Comment: 'But it is not working properly' - what exactly does not work?

Comment: error: "ws://localhost:8080/WebSocket1/websocket/web-client" cannot establish connection. This error message showing in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is...

Since you ServerEndpoint maps an argument "{client-id}" it should be present in the URL your client uses to connect.

Either you remove the parameter on server-side or you need to include a value to it on client-side.

Again, just guessing. It would be useful if you include more information regarding the issue (e.g., server logs)

[]s
Heleno